# SSRS report with each category a separate table/grid

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am using BIDS and SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) 2008 R2 to build a report. And I want the each category to show as a separate table/grid.

Important: the columns (CELERY, EGG etc) are dynamic and come from values in a table, so the person building the report cannot hard-code them into the report. So we are using a matrix control at the moment.

What the report looks like now: 
[image: before]

How I would like the report to look:
[image: after]

Any ideas?

Thanks, Craig

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a list ontrol and put the matrix inside the list. Use the category as your grouping for the list. Add a textbox just above the matrix to display the category.